# Supporting all video formats in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player, libvlc

I am building an app which allows users to upload videos from different devices including android and iOS then stream them from server with VideoView during playback. I end up with different video formats and get the inevitable "Cannot play this video" error on several occasions.

Some research says that videos with `format .mp4 and codec H.264` can work on all devices, so I have a few things I am working on.

1. Convert all videos on server side to the above mentioned format and codec
2. Use ffmpeg to convert the videos in app during playback
3. Use VLC sdk which supports a wide range of video formats

I am not sure which if these is the best solution, I have not worked with videos a lot in the past on Android and I am not sure what the pros and cons maybe or if indeed these are viable solutions or if this problem already has a known solution.

Comment: format .mp4 and codec H.264 can work on all devices ? No, though [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) says so, but from time to time some devices cannot playback these videos. Note that H.264 is video codec. The audio codec may not be supported.

Comment: Have you had to deal with this problem before? What is the best solution?

Comment: You're almost there. Use MP4 container format, with video codec H.264 AVC, and audio codec AAC. Remember you can't serve all devices in the world, as you're not working with iOS devices; Apple well defines the device formats, but not in Android's case

Comment: FFMPeg option is little complex but this is the best solution

Comment: @Raptor Do I do a sever side conversion or is it better in app?

Comment: @Dipu Yes I looked at few examples on this and they seem pretty complex. I also wasn't sure it is supported streaming, I want to avoid having to download the videos to device.

Comment: Server side for sure. I installed FFMPEG in my Ubuntu server & do conversion for all uploaded videos to ensure every device can view the video nicely.

Comment: The link provided by @Raptor mentions Baseline profile, so you will have to add `-profile:v baseline` to your `ffmpeg` command. The devices may also require a specific level, so you may also need to use `-level`. See the [FFmpeg H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).